# Subquery group by DISTINCT column

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, subquery, distinct

I have a **simplified** version of a query as follows:

```
SELECT
    count_last_8, goals_8, count_last_16, goals_16 
FROM (
    (
      SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS count_last_8,  f_total_ftg AS goals_8
      FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM results 
        ORDER BY f_datetime LIMIT 8 
      ) AS X 
    ) last_8g,
    (
      SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS count_last_16, f_total_ftg AS goals_16
      FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM results 
        ORDER BY f_datetime LIMIT 16 
      ) AS X 
    ) last_16g
);
```

I also have 2 columns in the `results` table - `f_player1` and `f_player2` and I want to group the query by the `DISTINCT` players

So the list of players would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f_player1 AS player 
FROM results 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT f_player2 AS player 
FROM results;
```

How can I add this condition so each table alias (`last8g`, `last16g`) applies to those distinct players?

Sample data with current query:

```
count_last_8    |   goals_8    | count_last_16   |  goals_16
    8                 4                16              4
```

And I'd want it kind of like as follows:

```
  player  |   count_last_8    |   goals_8    | count_last_16   |  goals_16
    kray           2                 2                4              9
    peli           1                 3                3              7
    etc...
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.

Comment: Ok I've added. thanks

Comment: provide the initial sample data i.e. data from which you want the final result.

Comment: Please also provide table description(s).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult to understand your question, it would be much easier with a real sample of data and also a real expected result based on the sample provided.

However, i tried something, it may be the solution or it may help you :

```
SELECT 
  T1.player, 
  T1.count_last_8, 
  T1.goals_8, 
  T2.count_last_16, 
  T2.goals_16
FROM(
  SELECT 
    f_player1 AS player, 
    SUM(c1) AS count_last_8, 
    SUM(c2) AS goals_8
  FROM(
    SELECT 
      f_player1, 
      COUNT(f_player1) AS c1, 
      SUM(f_total_ftg) AS c2 
    FROM(
      SELECT * 
      FROM 
        results
      ORDER BY f_datetime
      LIMIT 8
    ) ST1
    GROUP BY f_player1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      f_player2, 
      COUNT(f_player2) AS c1, 
      SUM(f_total_ftg) AS c2 
    FROM(
      SELECT * 
      FROM 
        results
      ORDER BY f_datetime
      LIMIT 8
    ) ST2
    GROUP BY f_player2 
  ) ST3
  GROUP BY f_player1
) T1
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    f_player1 AS player, 
    SUM(c1) AS count_last_16, 
    SUM(c2) AS goals_16
  FROM(
    SELECT f_player1, 
    COUNT(f_player1) AS c1, 
    SUM(f_total_ftg) AS c2 
    FROM(
      SELECT * 
      FROM 
        results
      ORDER BY f_datetime
      LIMIT 16
    ) ST4
    GROUP BY f_player1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      f_player2, 
      COUNT(f_player2) AS c1, 
      SUM(f_total_ftg) AS c2 
    FROM(
      SELECT * 
      FROM 
        results
      ORDER BY f_datetime
      LIMIT 16
    ) ST5
    GROUP BY f_player2
  ) ST6
  GROUP BY f_player1
) T2
ON T1.player = T2.player
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b47fab/37)

Comment: This is nearly right yes, but when you apply the limits, it's getting the first 8 and 16 records respectively from the table. Rather I need it to search the whole table and get the first 8 and 16 that fulfil the conditions on each column

Comment: What do you mean with "the first 8 and 16 that fulfil the conditions on each column" ? which conditions ?